# React native Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

So my project was working fine, but when i tried to generate the apk i got an error. So i deleted node_modules and installed again and i start to get this error

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.facebook.react:hermes-engine:+ as no versions of com.facebook.react:hermes-engine are available.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

How can i solve it? My react native version is 0.68.1

Answer (score 2):

Fix and updates on Android build failures happening since Nov 4th 2022 -- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

> Historically, the React Native template provided build.gradle files that contain a dependency on the React Native Android library as follows: implementation("com.facebook.react:react-native:+").

> Specifically, the + part of this dependency declaration is causing Gradle to pick the highest version among all the declared repositories (often referred as Gradle Dynamic versions). Till React Native version 0.70, we were shipping a Maven Repository inside the NPM package (inside the ./android folder). Starting from 0.71, we moved such folder and uploaded it to Maven Central.

> Using Gradle Dynamic versions (i.e. a + dependency) is considered an antipattern (see the various warnings and notes on this page), specifically as it can lead to scenarios like this one and generally exposes users to less-reproducible builds. This is exactly what happened in this scenario, as builds started failing without any changes to user projects.

> In 0.71 we cleaned up the new app template and removed all the + dependencies (see here) and we moved the template to use the React Native Gradle Plugin, which will allow us to prevent scenarios like this from happening in the future.

> Sadly, users on older versions, say 0.66.0, were still using a + version. This caused their build to query all the repositories for the highest available versions of the React Native. While the node_modules/react-native/android folder contained a valid 0.66.0 version, Gradle honoured the + version and fetched version 0.71.0-rc0 from Maven Central as it's higher from the semantic versioning ordering.

> The resolutionStrategy block in the fix is forcing the version of com.facebook.react:react-native to all the projects to the one provided by the version of React Native you're effectively using.

Comment: So does this mean that now that it's released, setting the react-native version to 71 should get rid of this problem, right? Because I'm facing this error after upgrading RN in a new project made with v70 to v71.